# Wagtail (Django) page not displaying due to TemplateDoesNotExist Error

Tags: python, django, wagtail

I have recently installed Wagtail CMS, into an existing Django Project.

I have created a new App in my existing Django project, and placed the following into the models.py.

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.db import models

from wagtail.wagtailcore.models import Page
from wagtail.wagtailcore.fields import RichTextField
from wagtail.wagtailadmin.edit_handlers import FieldPanel


class HomePage(Page):
    body = RichTextField(blank=True)

    content_panels = Page.content_panels + [
        FieldPanel('body', classname="full"),
    ]
```

If I visit the Wagtail CMS Admin, and then go to Explorer, and Add Child Page, I now see 'Home Page' as a new Page option. As desired.

However I have two problems: -

Firstly, only the title field is editable. The body field is not clickable. 
Secondly when I publish the new page I get a template error: -

```
TemplateDoesNotExist at /pages/test/

blog/home_page.html
```

I have checked the documentation here:

http://docs.wagtail.io/en/v1.9/getting_started/tutorial.html

and it states the following:

> The page template now needs to be updated to reflect the changes made
>   to the model. Wagtail uses normal Django templates to render each page
>   type. By default, it will look for a template filename formed from the
>   app and model name, separating capital letters with underscores (e.g.
>   HomePage within the ‘home’ app becomes home/home_page.html). This
>   template file can exist in any location recognised by Django’s
>   template rules; conventionally it is placed under a templates folder
>   within the app.

I created a home_page.html file in the blog app I created, and placed the following code into it:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% load wagtailcore_tags %}

{% block body_class %}template-homepage{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
    {{ page.body|richtext }}
{% endblock %}
```

But I am still getting the same error.

Can you advise how I can resolve template error, and (if connected) why the body field is not editable.

Thanks.

Comment: "I created a home_page.html file in the blog app I created" - where, exactly? As per the documentation, it needs to be in `blog/templates/blog/home_page.html`.

Comment: Thanks again @gasman, yes that fixed it. Now the page is loading. I am just seeing "template-homepage". On the page as that's the only text defined in the home_page.html apart from page.body. Do you have any idea why the body field is blank and not clickable on the page editor in the wagtail control panel?

Comment: @gasman Also as a last general question if you don't mind... The existing django app works fine, what I'm trying to achieve here is to have /blog off the main site and when it is accessed a page is displayed that lists last 3 blog posts belonging to either of 3 users at the top with option to click to see more posts, and under that have blog posts displayed from any other user. Broadly speaking is this something I should be able to achieve fairly easily and if so can you give me any pointers of the broad steps you might take if you were doing that?